# can we give datatype as decimal(2,2) or decimal(3,3) in SQL server ,

Tags: database

will it work according to the rules ???
I want to know it is correct or not?

I have error of arithmetic overflow error converting datatype to datatype numeric

I know we can write decimal(6,2)  for the value 1000

output:- 1000.00

Comment: *Can I do "X"* - well what happened *when you tried it for yourself*?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.  The following is from the [SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which I'd recommend reading through for better understanding.

The decimal type is defined as `decimal[ (p[ ,s] )]`

In the above statement, `p` represents precision, and `s` represents scale, which are both fixed numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1.

`p` is the maximum total number of decimal digits to be stored. This number includes both the left and the right sides of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

`s` is the number of decimal digits that are stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p, and can only be specified if precision is specified. The default scale is 0 and so 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Possible values range from `0.999` to `-0.999`

You can test that by casting a value to the data type

```
select cast(0.999 as decimal(3,3))
```

and see if it works or generates an arithmetic overflow.